# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable in my tensorflow custom training loop

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I've made my custom training loops, and when I trained my model for 8 epochs, I'm getting the error.

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Full output with error logs:

```
Epoch 000: Loss: 0.262, Accuracy: 91.380%
Epoch 001: Loss: 0.234, Accuracy: 91.320%
Epoch 002: Loss: 0.227, Accuracy: 92.120%
Epoch 003: Loss: 0.237, Accuracy: 91.820%
Epoch 004: Loss: 0.232, Accuracy: 92.400%
Epoch 005: Loss: 0.192, Accuracy: 93.780%
Epoch 006: Loss: 0.211, Accuracy: 93.280%
Epoch 007: Loss: 0.195, Accuracy: 94.100%
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-e6c924f8c071> in <module>()
      6                                                           optimizer_obj,
      7                                                           loss_obj,
----> 8                                                           grad)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Ps: The code was very large so check it [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1T1RiEn6fDcCUffFfxpWodSTFRNX0j96o?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 2):

You don't return anything in the `train_resnet` function, but you are trying to get some values from it:

```py
train_loss_results, train_accuracy_results = train_resnet(resnet_model, 
                                                          8, 
                                                          train_dataset, 
                                                          optimizer_obj, 
                                                          loss_obj, 
                                                          grad)
```

Just add `return train_loss_results, train_loss_accuracy` in the end of `train_resnet`

Comment: Thanks, don't know why I'm doing this type of silly mistakes. I think I need some hours of good sleep.

Comment: You are wellcome. If you think the answer is correct, please mark it